# How to create a datepicker textfield using Vuetify 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I'm using Vuetify 3 and want to have a textfield acting as a datepicker. You can see an example in the Vuetify 2 docs https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/#dialog-and-menu

The Vuetify 3 docs don't have such an example yet https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/

I started to prototype an example [Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-menu v-model="isMenuOpen" :close-on-content-click="false">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
          <v-text-field
            label="Selected date"
            :model-value="selectedDate"
            readonly
            v-bind="props"
          ></v-text-field>
        </template>
        <v-date-picker v-model="selectedDate"></v-date-picker>
      </v-menu>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  const isMenuOpen = ref(false)
  const selectedDate = ref()
</script>
```

How can I remove all the redundant things from the datepicker? I don't need

- the whole header
- the action bar at the bottom

So whenever I select a date I want the model to update

Answer (score 9):

Turned it into reusable DatePicker component:

*DatePicker.vue*

```
<template>
  <v-menu v-model="isMenuOpen" :close-on-content-click="false">
    <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
      <v-text-field
        :label="label"
        :model-value="formattedDate"
        readonly
        v-bind="props"
        variant="solo"
        hide-details
      ></v-text-field>
    </template>
    <v-date-picker v-model="selectedDate" hide-actions title="" :color="color">
      <template v-slot:header></template>
    </v-date-picker>
  </v-menu>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, computed, watch, defineProps, defineEmits } from "vue";

const { label, color, modelValue } = defineProps([
  "label",
  "color",
  "modelValue",
]);
const emit = defineEmits("update:modelValue");

const isMenuOpen = ref(false);
const selectedDate = ref(modelValue);

const formattedDate = computed(() => {
  return selectedDate.value ? selectedDate.value.toLocaleDateString("en") : "";
});

watch(modelValue, (newDate) => {
  selectedDate.value = newDate;
});

watch(selectedDate, (newDate) => {
  emit("update:modelValue", newDate);
});
</script>
<style>
.v-overlay__content:has(> .v-date-picker) {
  min-width: auto!important;
}
.v-picker-title {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
</style>`
```

*Parent.vue*

```
<date-picker
label="Start Date"
v-model="startDate"
color="primary"
></date-picker>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a computed like this:

```
  const formattedDate = computed(() => {
    return selectedDate.value.toLocaleDateString('en-US')
  })
```

And add the formattedDate as the model-value in your v-text-field

Comment: thanks for your reply. But first I'm looking for a way to remove all the unnecessary things from the picker component :)

Comment: Sorry, I completely misunderstood that. I would solve it using CSS as a last resort. But you are looking for a Vuetify-spicific configuration like "no-title" in Vuetify 2, right?.

Comment: yes. Basically I'm looking for the code for the Vuetify 2 examples ( like this https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/#formatting )

Answer (score 1):

- You can remove the action bar by setting a [`hide-action` boolean prop](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-date-picker/#props-hide-actions)

  ```
   <v-date-picker hide-actions>
  ```
- The [header is defined](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-date-picker/#slots-header) as [a named slot](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#named-slots), so to remove it, pass an empty template

  ```
   <v-date-picker>
       <template v-slot:header></template>
   </v-date-picker>
  ```
- The title is a prop itself, you can pass an empty string to remove it.

  ```
    <v-date-picker title="">
  ```

To remove title, header and actions, you could include a date picker like this

```
  <v-date-picker hide-actions title="">
      <template v-slot:header></template>
  </v-date-picker>
```

And [a demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqNUUuOAiEQvUqHtUCMs+o4E+cc4gKbmog2n0B1TybGu09Ba9LqQnfwePU+xfbMvmMU4wCsZWsEF3uN8KV806xH3gWP2npIFahQCr/Ncchof/4+FctRd8B1CoM3il1ZlWdIhkfbnSA1B2uI1KENPjdosQcandFp4ObcjDz3AdsDaEO2a3kXqVLlnfgtGaEUbQpO53nyOxG2YL31pyyOOXjqfC4TinU5K9Y220lNsQNizK2UnfHENNDbMQkPKH10krZV+m9WYiWWS2lsxhvGe73PoqoVqZ3yF3K0LoaE3On4YDs9VOuKFIyUyv1Fhg3RZBo8WgfcBFfDfExZZrCA7PieNpMhkYhii5lNCfyG1cu65PGkLclwhMQTePpISO9Wehib13p4eqpW3C9l4ZcFq2O0+Skz2/0Dpfz5DA==)

Comment: Note : at the time of writing, there's a bug involving `hide-actions` and `v-model` in vuetify 3.3.11 https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/17867 . A fix seems to be coming.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I want https://shorturl.at/DHIOV, based on your example :) With a sample locale ... But the locale provider doesn't seem to work yet